# Call specific functions (insert, delete) just from on controller and without mapping classes in dispatcherservlet

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, request-mapping

in spring every page or class is mapped in dispatcherservlet. But how could i call several function without mapping and just use one controller. all insert, delete functions will be defined in another class.

**index**

```
<a href="delete.htm">New Record</a>

<a href="insert.htm">New Record</a>
```

**function.java**

```
insert()
{
...............
}


delete()
{..................
}
```

**controller.java**

```
public class controller {

@RequestMapping(value = "/insert.htm")

public insert(){...................
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete.htm")

public delete(){....................
}

                 }
```

**dispatcherservlet**

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
```

Comment: `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` then you can use @Controller for controller class. Reference http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable

Comment: then what to do ,,, i have provided full code ,, not just for a comment ,, i want full code help

Comment: Please spend sometime and take a look at this tutorial. It's similar to what you're trying to do. It's easy to follow. I find it useful. http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/